# VueJS watching properties and changing data

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Suppose I have three fields:

[image]

Value should change when either percent or total has changed.
Total should change when value is changed.

Thus i created some watchers for those properties:

```
watch:{
  p: function(nv,ov){
    this.v = this.t * nv / 100;
  },
  t: function(nv,ov){
     this.v = nv * this.p / 100;
  },
  v: function(nv,ov){
    this.t = nv * this.p;
  }
  }
```

Currently the watchers trigger each other and that is probably why it is not working correctly.

Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jj65t449/

Comment: One way to get around the infinite updates would be to use computed values with a backing private data value. https://jsfiddle.net/jwgcptLh/6/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your values **don't converge**, because you have an **incorrect function**.

If `total`=`100`, `perc`=`11`, then `val`=`11`: which is `total * perc/100`, ok.

If `total`=`100`, `val`=`11`, then `perc`=`11`: which is `total * val/100`, ok.

If `perc`=`11`, `val`=`11`, then `total`=`100`: which is `val / perc * 100`, **not `val * perc` as you are using**.

Since you are using an invalid function, the total will be set to a crazy value, that will trigger a `val` update, that will trigger a `total` update again, snowballing them into infinite numbers (which is when the calculation stops, because they converged, as `infinity`=`infinity`).

So, if you correct your function, the infinite calculation will halt. Not because there is no cyclic dependency between those vars (there still is!), but because they will stop recalculating because the values will stop changing (they will converge).

**See demo below,** where I fixed the `v` watcher function. (Note that I had to use some `Math.round()` so they converge without changing the input numbers - remove them to see what I mean. The downside of this is, obviously, the numbers are rounded.)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    t: 100,
    p: 10,
    v: 10
  },
  watch: {
    p: function(nv, ov) {
      this.v = this.t * nv / 100;
    },
    t: function(nv, ov) {
      this.v = Math.round(nv * this.p / 100);
    },
    v: function(nv, ov) {
      this.t = Math.round(nv / this.p * 100);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  Total:<br/>
  <input type="number" v-model="t" />
  <hr/> Percent: <br/>
  <input type="number" v-model="p" />
  <hr/> Value:
  <br/>
  <input type="number" v-model="v" />
</div>
```

### After fixing the function, options if you don't want round numbers

First fix the function. Now, some options.

You can just remove the `Math.round()`. The downside is that sometimes when you modify the `v`, the cycle will end up modifying `v` back, by `0.0000001`. See demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    t: 100,
    p: 10,
    v: 10
  },
  watch: {
    p: function(nv, ov) {
      this.v = this.t * nv / 100;
    },
    t: function(nv, ov) {
      this.v = nv * this.p / 100;
    },
    v: function(nv, ov) {
      this.t = nv / this.p * 100;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  Total:<br/>
  <input type="number" v-model="t" />
  <hr/> Percent: <br/>
  <input type="number" v-model="p" />
  <hr/> Value:
  <br/>
  <input type="number" v-model="v" />
</div>
```

If you don't want the above, you will **have** to handle the cyclic dependency between vars.

### Working around the cyclic dependencies.

This is a common problem with Vue. There are some options, but they don't look pretty. Pick what suits you the best.

Changing the **watchers into methods** and removing `v-model`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    t: 100,
    p: 10,
    v: 10
  },
  methods: {
    updateP: function(newP) {
      this.p = newP;
      this.v = this.t * newP / 100;
    },
    updateT: function(newT) {
      this.t = newT;
      this.v = newT * this.p / 100;
    },
    updateV: function(newV) {
      this.v = newV;
      this.t = newV / this.p * 100;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  Total:<br/>
  <input type="number" :value="t" @input="updateT($event.target.value)" />
  <hr/> Percent: <br/>
  <input type="number" :value="p" @input="updateP($event.target.value)" />
  <hr/> Value:
  <br/>
  <input type="number" :value="v" @input="updateV($event.target.value)" />
</div>
```

Using **internal variables** to hold the values and use **"settable" computed** instead of watchers:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    tVal: 100,
    pVal: 10,
    vVal: 10
  },
  computed: {
    p: {
      get() { return this.pVal; },
      set(newP) { this.pVal = newP; this.vVal = this.tVal * newP / 100; }
    },
    t: {
      get() { return this.tVal; },
      set(newT) { this.tVal = newT; this.vVal = newT * this.pVal / 100; }
    },
    v: {
      get() { return this.vVal; },
      set(newV) { this.vVal = newV; this.tVal = newV / this.pVal * 100; }
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<div id="app">
  Total:<br/>
  <input type="number" v-model="t" />
  <hr/> Percent: <br/>
  <input type="number" v-model="p" />
  <hr/> Value:
  <br/>
  <input type="number" v-model="v" />
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @acdcjunior for the detailed answer. Indeed I was mainly interested in how to handle the cyclic dependecies.
The incorrect function was just a side effect when tossing together the fiddle. I turned to the solution with settable computed properties (which Bert already suggested) because using
the watchers in combination with Math.round causes some usability issued which you see here https://jsfiddle.net/rmzabmv3/ . If you decrease the total e.g. be using the numeric down arrow all numbers below < 5 are rounded to 0.

Comment: Yes. Makes complete sense. Good solution.